# How can I access global variable created by content script in console?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Sometimes I want get global variable value directly by console as page script and page console can.

Comment: [`window.wrappedJSObject.yourVariable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) is this what you want?

Comment: @tsh I don't want share or expose my extension's content script objects to page script at all, just I want view and modify content script objects in console as background script I can. In other word I need one console context in content script rather than page script or background script.

Comment: If you just want to view some object in console, why not just `console.log(theVariable)`?

Comment: @tsh Also sometimes I want modifier it, and frequently change what I want to view, the `console.log(variable)` need frequently change the content script file and reload my extension.